# How to reuse a cluster with Databricks Asset bundles

Tags: databricks

I am using Databricks asset bundles as an IAC tool with databricks. I want to create a cluster using DAB and then reuse the same cluster in multiple jobs. I can not find an example for this. Whatever examples I found out have all specified individual new clusters while defining a job. How can we reuse the clusters?